# Getting rid of duplicate array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

Array is like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2011/10/05
)
Array
(
    [0] => 2011/10/05
)
```

How can I get rid of the duplicate array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

php has a function

array_unique

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

EDIT

```
  Option 1
      <?php
           $array1 = array("2011/10/05"); 
           $array2 = array("2011/10/05"); 
           $merged = $array1;

           foreach($array2 as $v) array_push($merged,$v);
           $unique = array_unique($merged); 
      ?>
```

You could use array_merge, but the problem with array_merge is that it joins the same keys together which you probably don't want. The above code will add elements from array2 to array1 and then do array_unique (adding elements of array2 to array1 can also be done differently).

Comment: I used that, couldnt get it working. My code was: $date = array_unique($date);

Comment: post your array structure. Are there two arrays or only one? if there are several u have to merge them together and than do array_unique.

Comment: there seems to be 2 arrays:

Array
(
    [0] => 2011/10/05
)
Array
(
    [0] => 2011/10/05
)

How do I merge it then, do array unique. It is a multidimensional array btw. I have looked at array merge, but it seems that only works if you have two arrays in 2 seperate variables

Answer (score 0):

First merge and then unique

```
$a = array('2011/10/05');
$b = array('2011/10/05');

$c = array_merge($a,$b);

$d = array_unique($c);
```

Comment: array_merge will merge same keys even if it contains different values.

Comment: @blejzz If the keys are numeric, it will not happen . Only `array_merge_recursive` will merge with keys are  same and numeric.